# Node/Express: API using async await

Tags: node.js, express, mysql2

I'm new to node and wondering if I'm heading in the right direction with my usage of *async/await* in API design.

Currently this is just for a MVP project but I'm interested in learning good patterns.

Stack: Node, Express, MySQL (using `mysql2` package)

The following is a simplified version of my endpoint and should give you an idea of what I'm doing:

```
  createUser = async (req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const email = req.body.email;

    let query = 'insert into Users set name = ?, email = ?';
    const values = [name, email];
    query = mysql.format(query, values);

    let result;

    // in the project, this is abstracted
    try {
      const [rows] = await this.dbPool.execute(query);
      // do something with the result of the query. simplified eg:
      result = rows.insertId;
    } catch (err) {
      // handle error and assign appropriate value to result
    }

    res.send(result);
  };
```

The above code does what I want to do but I wonder if I'm committing a rookie mistake in the way in which *endpoint interacts with db*, that'll bite me in the future. (case of don't know what I don't know yet.) I'm not looking for general coding best practices (code above is simplified) though they're welcome.

Comment: *"Better"* how? If it's tested and working, what's the issue?

Comment: This might be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've edited my question; hopefully that will slim down what I'm looking for.

Comment: Instead of creating raw queries, I recommend you using a ORM. Im using `Objection.js` (that uses `Knex.js` query builder) and Im so happy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's preferable to put all code that can cause errors inside `try` block.

There's no need for `result` temporary variable. `res.send(rows.insertId)` can be put directly inside `try` block, because any error outside won't be handled by a middleware and will result in suspended request:

```
  createUser = async (req, res) => {
    try {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const email = req.body.email;

    let query = 'insert into Users set name = ?, email = ?';
    const values = [name, email];
    query = mysql.format(query, values);

      const [rows] = await this.dbPool.execute(query);
      // do something with the result of the query. simplified eg:
      res.send(rows.insertId);
    } catch (err) {
      // handle error and assign appropriate value to result
    }
  };
```

In other respects it's already good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to answer your question without a little more context and seeing the full project. As far as async/await goes, if its working, then its fine.

That being said, there is always room to do thing in a different way, which can improve flexibility and reusability of your code.

For example, adding validation, layering your express app, decoupling your application logic from frameworks, etc.

Here are some links for extra reading if you are interested:

https://github.com/i0natan/nodebestpractices

https://nodefunction.com/nodejs/node-js-roadmap-a-route-from-beginners-to-become-expert-developer